# Couldn't transfer nested folder from apache camel using sftp, what should i add to transfer the folder as well

Tags: apache, apache-camel, jsch, camel-ftp

I want to copy all the files and subfolders from my local machine to sftp server, While I was able to transfer files inside the folder I couldn't transfer nested folder.
The configure method of my custom route builder is as follows

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:data/inbox/?noop=true").
        to("sftp://192.168.**.**:22/Documents?noop=true&username=******&password=******&preferredAuthentications=publickey,password");  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation about the file component at: http://camel.apache.org/file2 and you can see there is a `recurisve` option. Set this option to `true` to transfer files from sub directories and their structures.